# Set size of Tkinter window in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I'm sure this should be simple but I'm new with tkinter. I was wondering how to set the size of a Tkinter window. Here's what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File",menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New", command=donothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="Open File...", command=donothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="Close", command=donothing)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit",menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=donothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Redo", command=donothing)

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="?",menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Check For Updates", command=update)
editMenu.add_command(label="Change log", command=change_log)
editMenu.add_command(label="About", command=donothing)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't provide what you have so far. Isolate your issue and provide a [mcve].

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49098565/7032856

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> try a search for tkinter geometry for other examples.
>   good reference is http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/lang/python/tkinter.pdf
>   page 15 geometry strings

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

# try fiddling with these root.geometry values
root.title('My tkinter size experiment')
root.minsize(width=100, height=100)
root.geometry('1000x920+0+0')

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File",menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New")
subMenu.add_command(label="Open File...")
subMenu.add_command(label="Close")
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit",menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Undo")
editMenu.add_command(label="Redo")

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="?",menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Check For Updates")
editMenu.add_command(label="Change log")
editMenu.add_command(label="About")


root.mainloop()
```