# How to set the size of a window?

Tags: python, tkinter, window, size, toplevel

How can I resize `root` window?

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
tk.mainloop()
```

---

How can I resize `window`?

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
window = tk.Toplevel(root)
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could set the size of a window (be it a `Tk` instance or `Toplevel` instance) using [`geometry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method) method:

```
# identical to root.geometry('256x512')
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(256, 512))
```

or:

```
# identical to window.geometry('512x256')
window.geometry('{}x{}'.format(512, 256))
```

---

Additionally using geometry method one could also determine the upper-left corner of a window:

```
window.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(16, 32))
```

or perhaps both at once:

```
#identical to window.geometry('512x256+16+32')
window.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(512, 256, 16, 32))
```

More generally one could use [`winfo_toplevel`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_toplevel-method) in order to easily set the size of the window from its children:

```
widget.winfo_toplevel().geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(512, 256, 16, 32))
```

## Example

Here's an example that sets both the size and placement coordinates of a window through a children widget's reference:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def on_button_press(widget):
    width = 512
    height = 256
    x = 16
    y = 32
    widget.winfo_toplevel().geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, x, y))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    button = tk.Button(window, text="Resize & Place")
    #the line below is related to calling a method when a button is pressed
    button['command'] = lambda w=button: on_button_press(w)
    button.pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```